# Permission denied (publickey). while using SCP command

Tags: scp, tomcat, ansible

I have tried to copy some file in tomcat using SCP command

`scp ubuntu@xxxxxxx:/opt/apache-tomcat-9.0.48/conf/server.xml .`

**ubuntu@xxxxxxx: Permission denied (publickey).**

help me to get out this

Thank in advance :)

Comment: Are you trying to use a **live** or **persistent live** Ubuntu system as server? I'm asking because of the user name 'ubuntu'. In that case I think you need a user with a password (which can be created in a persistent live system). - Otherwise, **if the system is an installed system** with a user name 'ubuntu', you may need **key authentication**. Please ask the administrator (if it is not you).

Comment: Are you connecting to an EC2 instance? 

Comment: @matigo yes i have one master machine and one slave machine i just wanted to copy some file in a remote machine and pasting into my master machine

Comment: @sudodus yes it's literally a live machine before copying a file i just have checked the connectivity between them and it's working fine on a remote machine and paste it into my local machine it won't working on it

it's not an authentication issue i think so

Comment: I have never used an EC2 instance, so I'm sorry, I cannot help you much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your answers in the comments, your servers are Amazon EC2 instances, which confirms that this very much is an authentication issue. You will need to use `scp` with the `-i` option and include the `.pem` that you use while SSHing into the machine:

```
scp -i ~/.ssh/amazon.pem ubuntu@xxxxxxx:/opt/apache-tomcat-9.0.48/conf/server.xml .
```

Be sure to replace `~/.ssh/amazon.pem` with the actual name and location of your private key.